# (laravel ) checkbox toggle is not working. And Changing text do not working either.What's wrong with mycode?

Tags: laravel-8

I am new to laravel and creating todo list.

I try to toggle checkbox.

BUt in checked method(the bottom of PostController), I can't even change text in the first place.

What's wrong with checked method?
I expect a problem in web.php.

I'm using laravel8.
thankyou for your help!

What's wrong with checked method?

```
(((PostController.php)))
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Http\Requests\PostRequest;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::latest()->get();

        return view('index')
            ->with(['posts' => $posts]);
    }

    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show')
            ->with(['post' => $post]);
    }

    public function checked(Post $post)
    {

        // $post->is_done = !$post->is_done;
        $post->title = 'hogehoge';

        $post->save();

        return redirect()
            ->route('posts.index');
    }
}
```

```
(((web.php)))
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('posts.index');

Route::get('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('posts.show')
    ->where('post', '[0-9]+');


Route::patch('/posts/{post}/checked', [PostController::class, 'checked'])
    ->name('posts.checked')
    ->where('post', '[0-9]+');
```

```
(((post table column)))
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->boolean('is_done')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps(); // created_at, updated_at
        });
    }
```